# Google Recaptcha seems not to work on Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, google-recaptcha

I tried now a lot of times on two magento2 instances to enable the google recaptcha function.

I followed these instruction:

`https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/security-google-recaptcha.html`

Website is:

`https://goldschmiede-jaqueline.de`

The Google Recaptcha symbol appears but I can put any cryptic mails i.e. in the newsletter and it goes through.

I also enabled the required php setting
`allow_url_fopen = On (1)`

This is the google admin console for recaptcha.
[image]

These are the magento2 settings
[image]

[image]

My question is how to debug this issue and am I wrong that cryptical emails could be set after enabling the recaptcha?? Has anyone the same issue?

UPDATE:
The V2 with "I am not a robot" works but the V3 invisible in the footer of the newsletter not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it using Contact Us.  Works fine from here. You should see my contact us email.  I had to choose the TAXI pictures.

[image]

Comment: Can u try the newsletter? The newsletter is setted up with recaptcha v3 invisible and send me a pic where the images appear

Comment: I see the newsletter on the front page.  There is no reCAPTCHA displayed and when entering an email address I get a reCAPTCHA error.  The badge that should be displayed is not visible.

Comment: can u share the error message because I can see the reCaptcha in the newsletter block... See my updated answer

Comment: Still no visible reCaptcha on the screen near the newsletter block, but it worked this time.  Shows successful.  Looks like you got it working!

Vielen Dank für Ihre Anmeldung zu unserem Newsletter.

Comment: So u cannot see the reCaptcha badge directly under "Subscribe" ??? No it is not working. A bot tries to automatically enters cryptic email adresses like:

jbhfkfdskjfbs@kjbsdkjfnde.com

Those entries should get blocked! And currently the ReCaptche ignors such cases and allows to register. The problem directly after is that an automated email is getting triggered and when the receiver is not available the email client throws an exception that the receiver is not a valid email adress...

Comment: What I see:
https://imgur.com/ZlYjfDO

Comment: thaths weird because I can see it and I asked a lot of other people. What are u using for a browser?

Comment: Ok currently we disabled it because it is not working

Comment: Tried it with Brave (shields on and off) and Firefox (ad blocker on and off) and it's not visible.  I can see it on our site (we use V3).  Google settings maybe when you signed up for the key or can you mix V2 and V3 on the same site?  Nice looking site and I wish you the best of luck solving this :)